# SSRS Datasource changed. Is there a log?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Does SQL Services Reporting Services have a log file that keeps track of changes made to configuration of reports?

I'm trying to see when datasources were changed specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
>   Services\LogFiles

on the server.

If you're on a multi-instance server, replace the MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER as appropriate. This does record changes to data sources, as well as loads of other stuff.

Comment: I have this (D:\MSSQL\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles) but the files in here have nothing to do with data source changes? All just errors... I can't find any other logfile

Comment: Make sure your looking inside the right file for your time period, and look for something like "Call to CreateDataSourceAction". I can see this in my log files when I change a Data Source.

Comment: By the way, my last comment was for doing an overwrite through Visual Studio. For changes through the Report Manager portal, or, more generally, the web service, for updates, look for "Call to SetDataSourceContentsAction".

Comment: Neither of those work but it appears to be because our log settings are not very verbose.. the issue has sorted itself out though so I'm just going to mark this as the answer as it will work for some

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ReportServer Database to look at the entire history of reports unless flushed.
Open your management studio where SSRS is installed and go to your report server database used by the report server.
You will then need to query it for required information.

Comment: Do you know which table I would be looking in for the history?

Comment: The executionlog and catalog tables might get you something.